# iPhone SDK FBConnect webcore decodeGIFFrame exec_bad_access

Tags: iphone, sdk, fbconnect

```
- (void)apiDialogFeedUser {
        SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

        NSArray* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"test",@"name",@"http://test.co.in",@"link", nil], nil];
        NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];

        NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       @"test", @"name",
                                       @"test", @"caption",
                                       @"test", @"description",
                                       @"http://test.co.in", @"link",
                                       @"http://test.co.in/images/b_freequote.jpg", @"picture",
                                       actionLinksStr, @"actions",
                                       nil];

        Demo1AppDelegate *delegate = (Demo1AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [[delegate facebook] dialog:@"feed"
                          andParams:params andDelegate:self];
    }
```

I am using the code above to post to Facebook wall. But after when the dialog opens its suddenly throwing exec_bad_access. Its pointing to decodeGIFFrame. I have no idea what it is. Can anybody suggest what the problem is? Hope everybody understood my question.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I found the problem is with Facebook AppId. When I tried it with Hackbook id this problem disappeared. But I don't know what settings in my AppId is causing this problem. Any idea?

Comment: I am answering my own question. When I changed the default logo of my application through developer.facebook.com its solved my issue. Its really worked!

Hope this will help somebody.

Comment: +1 for figuring a way around Facebook's oversight. This crash only occurred for me on iOS 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question. When I changed the default logo of my application through developer.facebook.com its solved my issue. Its really worked! Hope this will help somebody.